# Series plot pandas color

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

If s is a Series, I get an error message when I run the following command :

```
s.plot(style='k--', color='b')
```

The error message says that `[b]` is not a recognized color.

I am using pandas 0.11 .

Do you have the same problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is asking `style` to be `'k'` ([black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model)) and `'--'` (dashed) but passing the *additional* `color` `'b'` (blue), so matplotlib throws an exception (at having two colors).

To render a blue dashed line you can either do:

```
s.plot(style='b--')
s.plot(style='--', color='b')
```

Comment: If I want to add points in my graph with the style 'o--', only the first works : s.plot(style='bo--')